# Android : EditText Soft Keyboard is not hiding at first time press

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, keyboard

In my activity I have two Fragment.Both Fragment view I have EditText.I want to hide the soft keyboard on one of the EditText in a Fragment.

I try with this code in one fragment before layout setting

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

When I use this line of code keyboard is hiding in both Fragment.But I want to show keyboard in one Fragment View

I try another line of code at the time of EditText "OnTouchListener" and "OnClickListener"

```
   edt_dailNumber.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             closeKeyboard(getActivity(),edt_dailNumber.getWindowToken());
                return false;
            }
        });

        edt_dailNumber.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                closeKeyboard(getActivity(), edt_dailNumber.getWindowToken());
            }
        });



 public static void closeKeyboard(Context c, IBinder windowToken) {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) c.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0);
}
```

By using this code it is hiding the Soft KeyBoard.

But when I press/touch the EditText at the first time the KeyBoard is showing. After that the second time onwards the keyboard is hiding

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_dailNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".85"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dail_dailpad_hint_text_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_line_contacts"
           />
```

I didnt get why the Soft KeyBoard is show at the first time Press

Can any give me a solution for this problem

Thanks in advcance:)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your manifest file , which activity use to edit text put the single line 
android: windowSoftInputMode="stateHindden"

Answer (score 0):

Your soft keyboard hiding on second click because of , you are using an edittext. On the first click, your Edit Text will get focus. then the second click it calls the onClickListener. That's why its happening.

If you want to use edittext itself for this particalur task then it is better to use **setOnFocusChangeListener()** instead of **onClickListner()**.

**Change in Code :**

```
edt_dailNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus)
        {
             // Open keyboard
            ((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(searchEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        } else {
            // Close keyboard
            ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);            }
    }
});
```

Now you can manually open and hide keyboard by doing below code :

for open

```
setEditTextFocus(true);
```

And for closing :

```
setEditTextFocus(false);
```

And if you want to directly close the keyboard then write :

```
edt_dailNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: I tried ,still its not working,I just update in how edittext in layout, can you please look into that

Comment: dude remove setOnTouchListener() and setOnClickListener method from your code and use only setOnFocusChangeListener(). Then see it will work. I have tried it in my code and its worked.

Comment: dude  I commented both setOnTouchListener() and setOnClickListener. Now keyboard is  not hiding even second press

Comment: Do you want to hide keyboard afer entering text in edittext or just want to hide keyboad on click of edittext ?

Comment: This will hide the keyboard, but I want cursor position if there is a text in the edittext. I am doing a layout for number dail pad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93128/discussion-between-binil-surendran-and-kishudroid).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire the onClickListener of edittext each time you can use

android:focusable = "false"

in your edittext.. hope this will help you

Comment: i want to the cursor postion from  editText if der is a text. if i put android:focusable = "false", vl not get position

Comment: try using edittext.clearfocus() when you hide the softkeypad and edittext.requestFocus(); when you show the softkeypad..

Answer (score 0):

```
youredittextid.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

**
This will work for hide your keyword of edittext

**